# MediaPlayer button in my viewpager

Tags: android, media-player, android-viewpager

I am building an app with a viewpager horizontal swipe. all of the pager components function however I cannot get my button to play. There are no errors with the code, it just doesnt work. thanks for you help.

```
  package com.test.viewpager;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.Parcelable; 
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter; 
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;  

public class viewpager extends Activity {   
public MediaPlayer mp = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  


@Override         
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp == null) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(viewpager.this, R.raw.song1);
            mp.start();
            }else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
    }};

    if (btn != null)
        btn.setOnClickListener(listener);


                MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();                 
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);                
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);                 
    myPager.setCurrentItem(2);         }                  

public void farLeftButtonClick(View v)         {                 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Far Left Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }         

public void farRightButtonClick(View v)         {                
    Toast.makeText(this, "Far Right Elephant Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }          
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {                 
        public int getCount() {                         
            return 5;                 }                  
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {                          
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()                                         
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                          
            int resId = 0;                        
            switch (position) {                         
            case 0:                                
                resId = R.layout.page1;                                
                break;                        
                case 1:                                
                    resId = R.layout.page2;                                
                    break;                        
                    case 2:                                
                        resId = R.layout.page3;                               
                        break;                         
                        case 3:                                
                            resId = R.layout.page4;                                
                            break;                         
                            case 4:                                
                                resId = R.layout.page5;                                 
                                break;                         }                          
            View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);                        
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);                         
            return view;                 }                  
        @Override                
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {                        
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);                  }                 
        @Override                
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {                        
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
            }                 
            @Override                
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {                        
                return arg0 == ((View) arg1);                  }                 
            @Override                 
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {                         
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                }                  
            @Override                 
            public Parcelable saveState() {                        
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                         
                return null;                 }                 
            @Override                
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {                       
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                 
            }}
    }
```

Here is the main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
     android:layout_height="match_parent"   
      android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

here is one of the panes page3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/newbutton"
    android:layout_gravity= "center"

   />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot get my button to play. There are no errors with the code, it
>   just doesnt work

That's because you're trying to inflate the button as part of the Activity's layout (main.xml). However, as you can already tell from the layouts you posted: that's not the case. The button is part of the 'page' that is displayed in the ViewPager; hence, move the button logic from the Activity's `onCreate(...)` to the PagerAdapter's `instantiateItem(...)`.

That will yield something like this:

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {                          
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // switch/case omitted for simplicity

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    if (btn != null) btn.setOnClickListener(new View.new OnClickListener(){
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp == null) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(viewpager.this, R.raw.song1);
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.stop();
                mp = null;
            }
        }
    });

    // add and return view etc.
}
```